# Why ____ (waste) our time waiting? Let's phone Mrs Caroll now

Tags: word-choice

Why is the correct answer "waste"? Don't we need an auxiliary verb? E.g. *Why are we wasting* or *Why do we waste*?

I can't seem to figure out why "waste" is correct.

Comment: Welcome! The issue here is that your proposed sentences use the present tense to indicate that the wasting *is* actually happening. The example uses the "zero infinitive" to talk about *hypothetical* time wasting (see [the bottom of this page](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/)).

Comment: We don't need an auxiliary verb. Both of your other suggestions are perfectly grammatical, but they involve introducing the word *we*, which presumably wasn't what the person who wrote the question intended.

Comment: Because English.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Andy Bonner and Peter Shor. I get it now:)